# DateTime->modify('+1 day') on for loop changes another variable

Tags: php, loops, datetime, for-loop

It's changes `$iDATEs` to 2019-08-11. I guess the reason is `$i=$iDATEs` and `$i->modify('+1 day')`

```
<?php
$iDATEs = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $_POST['fDATEs'].' 00:00:00');//2019-08-01
$iDATEe = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $_POST['fDATEe'].' 00:00:00');//2019-08-10
for ($i=$iDATEs; $i <= $iDATEe; $i=$i->modify('+1 day')) {
echo $i->format("Y-m-d").'<br>';
//It's show 2019-08-01 to 2019-08-10
}
echo $iDATEs->format("Y-m-d").'<br>';//It's changes $iDATEs to 2019-08-11. I guess the reason is $i=$iDATEs and $i->modify('+1 day')
echo $iDATEe->format("Y-m-d").'<br>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the `modify()` method of `DateTime` returns a `DateTime` variable it does so for chaining but it modifies the value of the variable itself, it doesn't return a new instance. This is true for any method that changes the object: `add`, `sub`...

You can use [`DateTimeImmutable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) that never modifies the original variable.

```
$iDATEs = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $_POST['fDATEs'].' 00:00:00');
$iDATEe = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $_POST['fDATEe'].' 00:00:00');
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/4LWu1)